# WordPress remove_filter() to remove theme JS hook via plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, oop

I have a theme that is adding a custom, full-screen background image via jQuery. The theme is doing this via a `class` object called `td_background`. Within the class is a function called `wp_head_hook()`, and within this hook, a filter is being added for the custom bg. It looks something like this:

```
class td_background {
    // ..some stuff

    function __construct() {
        add_action('wp_head', array($this, 'wp_head_hook'), 10);
    }

    function wp_head_hook() {
        add_filter( 'td_js_buffer_footer_render', array($this, 'add_js_hook'));
    }

    function add_js_hook($js) {
        // Custom JS added here for background image
        return $js
    }

}
new td_background();
```

I'm now trying to de-register the `add_js_hook` in a custom plugin I'm writing, but am having trouble wrapping my mind around how to do it with all this nesting. I've tried a few things, such as:

```
<?php
    // This...
    remove_filter( 'wp_footer', array($td_background, 'td_js_buffer_footer_render'));
    // ...and this
    remove_filter( 'wp_footer', 'td_js_buffer_footer_render');
    // ...and even
    remove_filter( 'wp_footer', 'add_js_hook', 100);
?>
```

I've also tried changing the above to `wp_head`.

Thoughts? My end goal is to de-register this JavaScript in the footer, so that I can add my own in place of it.

Comment: It's being instantiated anonymously, you're gonna [need this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57079/how-to-remove-a-filter-that-is-an-anonymous-object/57088#57088)

Comment: Cool info, but doesn't seem to be it...At least I'm not seeing this listed as an anonymous function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's being instantiated anonymously, we have to use the handy function [**`remove_anonymous_object_filter()`**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57079/how-to-remove-a-filter-that-is-an-anonymous-object/57088#57088) from WPSE, it would be something like:

```
// Run this from a plugin
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'kill_anonymous_example', 0 );

function kill_anonymous_example() {
    remove_anonymous_object_filter(
         'wp_head',
         'td_background',
         'wp_head_hook'
    );
}
```

I tested killing `wp_head` as I don't have a `td_js_buffer_footer_render` running.

Comment: Getting closer with this. I was able to remove the background...but there are other filters that are added under `wp_head_hook` that also are killed in the process. Any suggestions for targeting a single filter?

Comment: Try `remove_anonymous_object_filter( 'td_js_buffer_footer_render', 'td_background', 'add_js_hook' );`

Comment: Background re-appears. Since your answer does actually result in a change, I'm going to try to dissect what's actually going on. I'm sure I'll figure it out if I examine the `remove_anonymous_object_filter()` a bit more.

Comment: Yep, I'd go after what `apply_filters('td_js_buffer_footer_render',/*etc*/)` is doing

Comment: Brilliant! It ended up being `remove_anonymous_object_filter('td_js_buffer_footer_render', 'td_background', 'add_js_hook' );`. The only difference was adding the action to the `wp_footer` hook, rather than `template_redirect`. Many thanks!

Comment: Oh, yeah, I forgot that detail, the starting hook is important :D

Comment: I completely overlooked it as well. Thanks again.